# poetry install fail build with private dependency

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a module that depends on another module (`module_a`) stored in my private repository (nexus) that reuqest another module (`module_b`) at build time, even stored in the private repository.

I add repository source on `poetry.toml` in order to add my private repo.

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "nexus"
url = "https://my_nexus_url/private_repo/simple"
secondary = true
```

Then I specify the dependency on th toml

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9.0,<3.11,"
module_a="1.0.0"
```

When I run `poetry install` it download `module_a` and build it. During the build process I get this error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement module_b==1.0.1
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for module_b==1.0.1
```

When I try to install the module using `pip` with `--extra-index-url <my repo>` everything works fine.

```
pip install module_a --extra-index-url https://my_nexus_url/private_repo/simple
```

I guess that the problem is releted on the pip command, executed by `poetry`. It dose not specify the extra-index-url that point to my repo so it try to download dependency (`module_b`) from pypi repository instead from my repo.

There is a way to instruct poetry in order to use my private repo when source build is required?

I have already try with this:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9.0,<3.11,"
module_b={version="1.0.1", source="nexus"}
module_a={version="1.0.0", source="nexus"}
```

without any success.

Comment: Something is not clear to me: is `module_b` a build-time or a run-time dependency of `module_a`? -- Do you have control over the source code (and packaging) of `module_a` (and  `module_b`)?

Comment: `module_b` its a build-time dependency for `module_a`. I have access to the source code but the code repo is maintained by another teams so if it is no strictly necessary I don't want to touch it.

Comment: Your nexus does not have wheels of `module_a`? That would probably be best, because `module_b` could be ignored in the context of the question.

Comment: all the dependencies are on the nexus repository. If I run install with `pip` and `--extra-index-url` option, everything is build and installed correctly ( this is instrction was provided by the team that develop `module_a`. I am relatively new to python world, I worked  for many years with java and maven. What do you mean with wheels?

Comment: Wheels are ["built distributions"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/flow/#build-artifacts), so if there was a wheel of `module_a` on your Nexus then pip (or poetry) would install directly from this pre-built wheel and would completely ignore `module_b` (pip would have no need to know about `module_b`). -- So if possible the team maintaining your two libraries should publish both sdists and wheels to Nexus, this would make everything much easier.

Comment: I asked and  they said to me that a pre-build actually could not be enabled because the `module_a` should work on linux and windows, but the build pipeline actually don't support mutliple target build, so build on the fly is the only way actually.

Comment: I am running into this problem as well. It seems to be introduced in poetry version 1.3.0, which was released on Dec 9, 22.

It seems that poetry respects the source config for dependencies, but not for dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: @TriNguyen actually the only solution that I found is to use pip to install the `module_a` that depend on `module_b`. I install my dependencies with pip and tha I run poetry install and everything works fine.